# passing a function as an argument to a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have a function is given by :

```
import scipy.special
def p(z):
    z0=1./3.;eta=1.0
    value=eta*(z**2)*numpy.exp(-1*(z/z0)**eta)/scipy.special.gamma(3./eta)/z0**3 
    return value
```

I want to pass this function to the following class which is in the file called `redshift_probability.py` as an argument `p`:

```
import pylab
import numpy
import pylab
import numpy

class GeneralRandom:
  """This class enables us to generate random numbers with an arbitrary 
  distribution."""

  def __init__(self, x = pylab.arange(-1.0, 1.0, .01), p = None, Nrl = 1000):
    """Initialize the lookup table (with default values if necessary)
    Inputs:
    x = random number values
    p = probability density profile at that point
    Nrl = number of reverse look up values between 0 and 1"""  
    if p == None:
      p = pylab.exp(-10*x**2.0)
    self.set_pdf(x, p, Nrl)

  def set_pdf(self, x, p, Nrl = 1000):
    """Generate the lookup tables. 
    x is the value of the random variate
    pdf is its probability density
    cdf is the cumulative pdf
    inversecdf is the inverse look up table

    """

    self.x = x
    self.pdf = p/p.sum() #normalize it
    self.cdf = self.pdf.cumsum()
    self.inversecdfbins = Nrl
    self.Nrl = Nrl
    y = pylab.arange(Nrl)/float(Nrl)
    delta = 1.0/Nrl
    self.inversecdf = pylab.zeros(Nrl)    
    self.inversecdf[0] = self.x[0]
    cdf_idx = 0
    for n in xrange(1,self.inversecdfbins):
      while self.cdf[cdf_idx] < y[n] and cdf_idx < Nrl:
        cdf_idx += 1
      self.inversecdf[n] = self.x[cdf_idx-1] + (self.x[cdf_idx] - self.x[cdf_idx-1]) * (y[n] - self.cdf[cdf_idx-1])/(self.cdf[cdf_idx] - self.cdf[cdf_idx-1]) 
      if cdf_idx >= Nrl:
        break
    self.delta_inversecdf = pylab.concatenate((pylab.diff(self.inversecdf), [0]))

  def random(self, N = 1000):
    """Give us N random numbers with the requested distribution"""

    idx_f = numpy.random.uniform(size = N, high = self.Nrl-1)
    idx = pylab.array([idx_f],'i')
    y = self.inversecdf[idx] + (idx_f - idx)*self.delta_inversecdf[idx]

    return y
```

I don't know how to pass input argument `x` as an input parameter to function `p(z)` when I call the class

```
 from redshift_probability import GeneralRandom
 z_pdf=GeneralRandom()
```

If I do as following I get error:

```
 z_pdf.set_pdf( x=numpy.arange(0, 1.5, .001),p(x),N=1000000)
```

How do I modify it?

Comment: Have you tried with `z_pdf.set_pdf( x=numpy.arange(0, 1.5, .001),p,N=1000000)`. In that way, you pass the fonction and not the function applied on x... I guess that would do the trick

Comment: Can you edit GeneralRandom? I don't think you can do what you're trying in the method call itself.

Comment: yes, I did! I got this error message:`File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
`

Comment: @Dalek that error could be fixed with `z_pdf.set_pdf( x=numpy.arange(0, 1.5, .001),p=p,N=1000000)` Note the `p=p`. However, it doesn't look like that method expects p to be a function.

Comment: @dano you mean define the `p` function inside the class? is there anyway to make it general?

Comment: @dano I got this error message :`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: set_pdf() got an unexpected keyword argument 'N'`

Comment: Yeah, it's expecting `Nrl`, not `N`.

Comment: @dano shouldn't `x` be defined as a pointer to pass the argument to `p`? I have an idea but I don't know how to implement it?!!

Comment: There are no pointers in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change `GeneralRandom.__init__` to look like this:

```
  def __init__(self, x = pylab.arange(-1.0, 1.0, .01), p_func=None, Nrl = 1000):
    """Initialize the lookup table (with default values if necessary)
    Inputs:
    x = random number values
    p_func = function to compute probability density profile at that point
    Nrl = number of reverse look up values between 0 and 1"""  
    if p_func is None:
        self.p_val = pylab.exp(-10*x**2.0)
    else:
        self.p_val = p_func(x)
```

Then call it like this:

```
GeneralRandom(p_func=p)
```

That way, if you provide `p_func` it will be called with `x` as an argument, but if it's not provided, it gets set the same default as before. There's no need to call `set_pdf` explicitly, because it's called at the end of `__init__`.

Comment: It is not working like this, I still get this error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: set_pdf() got an unexpected keyword argument 'p_func'
`

Comment: @Dalek sorry, wasn't thinking there . I edited my answer

Comment: Then how do you get the quantity computed with `set_pdf`, especially if I would like to compute it for different `x` or `Nrl`??

Comment: @Dalek, will you ever need to compute it for a different `p_val`? Also, `set_pdf` doesn't return anything, it just sets `self.inversecdf`

Comment: I edited my example to save `p_val` to `self`, so you if you do `gen_rand = GeneralRandom(p_func=p)`, you can call `gen_rand.set_pdf(new_x, gen_rand.p_val, Nrl=some_new_val)` later.

Comment: I also need to call `gen_rand.set_pdf(pylab.arange(0.0, 1.5, .001), gen_rand.p_val,Nrl=10000)` and then if I want to get the quantity for `pdf` then it should be `zpfd= gen_rand.pdf`, right?